# Stable Baselines 3 support for Farama Gymnasium

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am building an environment in the maintained fork of `gym`: `Gymnasium` by Farama. In my `gym environment`, I state that the `action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(5)` and the `observation_space = gym.spaces.MultiBinary(25)`. Running the environment with the agent-environment loop suggested on the [Gym Basic Usage](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/basic_usage/) website runs with no problems: I registered the environment and it is simply callable by `gym.make()`.

However, I want to now train a reinforcement learning agent on this environment. Now I have come across `Stable Baselines3`, which makes a DQN agent implementation fairly easy. However, it does seem to support the new `Gymnasium`. Namely:

```py
import gymnasium as gym
from stable_baselines3.ppo.policies import MlpPolicy
from stable_baselines3 import DQN

env = gym.make("myEnv")
model = DQN(MlpPolicy, env, verbose=1)
```

*Yes I know, "myEnv" is not reproducable, but the environment itself is too large (along with the structure of the file system), but that is not the point of this question*

This code produces an error:

```py
AssertionError: The algorithm only supports (<class 'gym.spaces.discrete.Discrete',) as action spaces but Discrete(5) was provided
```

My question is the following: does Stable Baselines3 support `Gymnasium`?

I have tried to instead use `gym.spaces` in order to define the `action_space` and `observation_space`, such that

```py
from gym.spaces import Discrete, MultiBinary
action_space = Discrete(5)
observation_space = MultiBinary(25)
```

but along with this, I have to rewrite a large portion of the environment to support the old `gym` package. I wonder whether there is a better solution than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a bit confused by the other answer here as I was sure I'd seen gymnasium in the Stable Baselines 3 docs somewhere. Sure enough, it's even in the most basic "getting started" example: https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/quickstart.html.

However, I just tried running exactly this code and received the same error as the OP. Replacing gymnasium with gym 0.21 in the same example works without a problem.

Edit: The "getting started" example using gymnasium works with stable_baselines3 version 2.0.0a1 and above.

Comment: I see that I forgot to denote that in my OP, but I have been using gym >= 0.26. I guess there are some inconsistances between 0.21 and 0.26 if we are talking about stable baselines 3. I remember switching to 0.26 since the interchange between rendering in the agent-environment loop and gym.env are inconsistent between these versions. Good to denote though, that it apparently does work with 0.21!

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit, but your code should work with gymnasium as well if you upgrade to version 2.0.0a1 or later.

Comment: Right! I marked your thread as answer

Comment: For the record, I think the other answer was correct when it was posted :)

Answer (score 1):

> does Stable Baselines3 support Gymnasium?

If you look into [`setup.py`](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/setup.py#L102), you will see that a master branch as well as a PyPI release are both coupled with gym 0.21.

However, there is a [branch](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/pull/1327) with a support for Gymnasium. I haven't tested it yet, I think it is going to be merged into master in several weeks, then I will migrate myself. So far this is the current state of the art.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you possibly know an estimate of the date? Like, do you know if several weeks is around a month or do we look at three months?

Comment: taking into account that the current state of the corresponding PR is "draft" -- I wouldn't expect it to be merged earlier than this summer